# Close position Bitget Futures using ccxt

Tags: python, ccxt

I am trying to close a position on Bitget using CCXT. I have a long position that I would like to close

```
long_order = exchange.create_order(symbol, type='market', side='buy', amount=0.001)
```

From what I know with CCXT, we need to create an opposing order to close the position. I tried the code below but it opens a new short position and not close the long position.

```
exchange.create_order(symbol, 'market', side='sell', amount=0.001,
                                  params={'reduce_only': True})
```

Am I missing anything or is there any other way to close the long position?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the Bitget exchange has hedge mode set by default, which means that you can have two opposite positions open at the same time.

The good news is that the Bidget exchange has added the option to switch hedge mode to one way mode. After switching to one way mode in the platform, the position will be closed when the opposite position of the same size is opened.

**What is Hedge Mode?**

- When you trade with One-Way Mode, your positions can be open only in one direction - Long or Short.
- Hedge Mode allows you to keep a Long and Short position at the same time for your same trading pair.

**Links**

- [Bitget's Announcement on the Official Opening of the One-way Mode for Futures](https://www.bitget.com/en/support/articles/12560603776140)
- [Bitget Futures: One-Way Mode](https://www.bitget.com/academy/Bitget-Futures-One-Way-Mode)